# No response From DocumentDB CreateStoredProcedureAsync()

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I use this code to create a StoredProcedure in Azure-Documentdb. when its executed , it doesn't response any result to "sproc" inside "if" condition. But SP has created in Azure-DocumentDB,
**Edited with full code**

```
            var isUserExist= false;

        //string commandText = m_EtikadoUser.commandText;
        var collection = await GetOrCreateCollectionAsync();
        try
        {
            string scriptFileName = @"C:\Users\PC24\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Etikado_Web\EtikadoBusinessEntity\StoredPprocedures\GetUserByUserNameAndPassword.js";
            string scriptId = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(scriptFileName);

            var sproc = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure
            {
                Id = scriptId,
                Body = File.ReadAllText(scriptFileName)
            };


            //var sproc1=await client.creates

            var sproc1 = (from sp in client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.SelfLink)
                          where sp.Id == sproc.Id
                          select sp).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
            if (sproc1 == null)
            {
                sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collection.SelfLink, sproc);
            }
            var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(sproc.SelfLink);//, m_EtikadoUser.Name, m_EtikadoUser.Password);
            if (response != null)
            {
                isUserExist = true;
                await client.DeleteStoredProcedureAsync(sproc.SelfLink);
            }
            //var queryPrint = await client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.SelfLink, "SELECT * FROM c where c.Name = '" + m_EtikadoUser.Name + "' and c.Password='" + m_EtikadoUser.Password + "'");
            //isUserExist = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return isUserExist;
```

Here Is My SP:

```
function simple(prefix) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();

// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    //'SELECT * FROM c where c.Name = "' + UserName + '" and c.Password="' + Password + '"',
    "SELECT * FROM c",
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if it's empty, set the body to 'no docs found',
        // Otherwise just take 1st element from the feed.
        if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody("no docs found");
        else getContext().getResponse().setBody(prefix + JSON.stringify(feed[0]));
    });

if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("The query wasn't accepted by the server. Try again/use continuation token between API and script.");
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the method that creates the stored procedure?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  it has in first code block

    "sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collection.SelfLink, sproc);"

Comment: I Mean higher up the call chain. Are you blocking with `.Result` or `.Wait`?

Comment: Still doesn't answer my previous question. Are you synchronously blocking anywhere higher up in the method chain?

Comment: you might want to go into Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Enable "Break when exceptions cross...", see if any other exceptions are being thrown...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not synchronously. i use await for get "collection.SelfLink"  Collection Link

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have removed "await" then its work . how does it happen could you please ex-plane it for me . Thank you

Comment: Removed `await` from where?

Comment: Hi @YuvalItzchakov im froma same team.. when execute following code line.. it doesn't give any response. so we tried by removing await.. then code executer just pass the line without any return value.. it just read the sp.. please help with this matter..  
if (sproc1 == null)
            {
                sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collection.SelfLink, sproc);
            }